# Filtering data by drop down in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

This is my first attempt at Laravel and I got stuck trying to filter my data according to my drop down list.

I have an index page where data for a vehicle log sheet is captured but I cant seem to figure out the MYSQL to filter it based on the dropdown item I pick. If the user picks a staff name from the dropdown and click the filter button, it should show all the records for that staff member.

my controller:

```
 public function vehiclereport()
    {

        // $energy = Maintenance::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
        $energy = VehicleLog::join('vehicle', 'vehicleslog.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicle.id')
            ->join('staff', 'vehicleslog.staff_key', '=', 'staff.smsstaff_key')
            ->get();

        $cars = Vehicle::get();
        $staff = Staff::all();
        
        return view('admin.vehiclereport', compact('energy', 'cars', 'staff'));
    }
```

Has anyone done this, or know a way?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the most simplistic solution to get you started:

```
 public function vehiclereport()
    {

        $energy = VehicleLog::join('vehicle', 'vehicleslog.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicle.id')
            ->join('staff', 'vehicleslog.staff_key', '=', 'staff.smsstaff_key')
            ->when(request()->input('staff_id'), function ($query) {
                   $query->where('staff.id', request()->input('staff_id'))
             })
            ->get();

        $cars = Vehicle::get();
        $staff = Staff::all();
        
        return view('admin.vehiclereport', compact('energy', 'cars', 'staff'));
    }
```

Then you need to modify your view to add:

```
<form>
<select name="staff_id" id="staff_id">
<option></option>
@foreach ($staff as $staffMember) 
    <option value="{{$staffMember->id}}" {{request()->input('staff_id') === $staffMember->id ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}}>{{$staffMember->name}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
<button>Filter by selected staff member</button>
</form>
```

This should be the most basic example which does a full page refresh and filters the list by the option you selected.

If you want something more complicated I suggest reading more tutorials by good providers like e.g. [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/)

Comment: I will definitely give this a try. It just needs to display all the records for that member of staff that's selected

Comment: it returns a `Too few arguments to function` error. Any idea what causes this?

Comment: I forgot to close the `input(...)` function call

Comment: I did Close it but still the same issue

Comment: Try the updated code

Answer (score 0):

Try with leftjoin

**Replace** code as

```
 public function vehiclereport()
    {

        // $energy = Maintenance::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
        $energy = VehicleLog::leftJoin('vehicle', 'vehicleslog.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicle.id')
            ->leftJoin('staff', 'vehicleslog.staff_key', '=', 'staff.smsstaff_key')
            ->get();

        $cars = Vehicle::get();
        $staff = Staff::all();
        
        return view('admin.vehiclereport', compact('energy', 'cars', 'staff'));
    }
```